# Using grep to subset rows from a data.table, comparing row content

Tags: r, data.table, string-matching

```
DT <- data.table(num=c("20031111","1112003","23423","2222004"),y=c("2003","2003","2003","2004"))

> DT
    num    y
1: 20031111 2003
2:  1112003 2003
3:    23423 2003
4:  2222004 2004
```

I want to compare the two cell content, and perform an action based on the boolean value. for instance, if "num" matches the year, create a column x holding that value. I thought about subsetting based on grep, and that works, but naturally checks the *whole* column every time which seems wasteful

```
DT[grep(y,num)] # works with a pattern>1 warning
```

I could apply() my way but perhaps there's a data.table way?

Thanks

Comment: @Frank: I didn't; I changed the question to **match the question**, namely [the redirected question on grepl and stringi which we both just contributed on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400250/memory-and-performance-using-grepl-on-large-data-table). If you're not going to enlarge this title to make it sufficiently broad as a primary source, please revert that redirect. R has many many more string-matching functions than just `grep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're happy using the `stringi` package, this is a way that takes advantage of the fact that the `stringi` functions vectorise both pattern and string:

```
DT[stri_detect_fixed(num, y), x := num])
```

Depending on the data, it may be faster than the method posted by Veerenda Gadekar.

```
DT <- data.table(num=paste0(sample(1000), sample(2001:2010, 1000, TRUE)),
                 y=as.character(sample(2001:2010, 1000, TRUE)))
microbenchmark(
    vg = DT[, x := grep(y, num, value=TRUE, fixed=TRUE), by = .(num, y)],
    nk = DT[stri_detect_fixed(num, y), x := num]
)

#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   vg 6027.674 6176.397 6513.860 6278.689 6370.789 9590.398   100
#   nk  975.260 1007.591 1116.594 1047.334 1110.734 3833.051   100
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg changed to `stri_detect_fixed`

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
DT[, x := grep(y, num, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE), by = .(num, y)]

#> DT
#        num    y        x
#1: 20031111 2003 20031111
#2:  1112003 2003  1112003
#3:    23423 2003       NA
#4:  2222004 2004  2222004
```

Comment: Great! thanks... haven't thought of "value" option.Also though subsetting would be better for some reason