# Memory and Performance using grepl on large data.table

Tags: r, regex, performance, data.table

I'm performing a simple command in R over a large dataset, and the result is slow and uses too much memory.  Here's a an example using two rows, although my real dataset has 154 million rows:

```
library(data.table)
Dt<-data.table(title1=c("The coolest song ever",
"The greatest music in the world"),
title2=c("coolest song","greatest music"))

Dt$Match<-sapply(seq_len(nrow(Dt)), function(x) grepl(Dt$title2[x],Dt$title1[x]))
```

The result of Dt$Match should be TRUE, TRUE.
Before running this script, I have about 12 Gb of RAM left, but as this slow code runs, memory is being used up.

Is there a more efficient way to get the same results?  Perhaps leveraging the Data Table package?

Comment: You've got the `grepl` arguments the wrong way around, should be `grepl(Dt$title2[x],Dt$title1[x])`

Comment: Maybe you should use a literal search with `fixed=TRUE` with `grepl`.

Comment: smci - you are correct.  Example fixed.

Comment: How about just `Dt[, Match := grepl(title2, title1, fixed = TRUE), by = title2]`?

Comment: In my dataset, title2 sometimes repeats.  Is the "by" argument necessary?

Comment: Yes it is necessary. But each group will be checked only once, no matter how many duplicates you have in `title2`. Did you even try the code?

Comment: The "by" argument has to apply to every row somehow.  Can't figure it out.  Yes, tried the code on 10,000 rows of my dataset and received lots of warnings:  "RHS 1 is length 10000 (greater than the size (1) of group 25). The last 9999 element(s) will be discarded."

Comment: Try `Dt[, Match := grepl(title2, title1, fixed = TRUE), by = .(title2, title1)]`

Comment: If I add a row number and group by the row number it works, and it is about 10x faster than old code. Thank you for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: I don't think you need to group by row. Try my comment above.

Comment: @DavidArenburg There's a good chance `.(title2,title1)` determines a unique row, I figure.

Comment: @Frank unless there are dupes in both. I'm still not sure why my original code doesn't work. Couldn't reproduce the behavior he mentions.

Comment: There are in fact dupes in both.  Of course, my example didn't capture that, so you could not have known that.

Comment: Your code also fixed the memory problem (hardly used any memory), so thanks, again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `stringi` library, it's more performant.

`stri_detect_fixed(Dt$title1, Dt$title2)` should be what you're looking for.

(thanks to Frank. Frank actually found the exact DT answer:

```
Dt[, stri_detect_fixed(title1, title2)]
```

The functions with suffix `..._fixed` are faster than the `_regex` ones.

Comment: @Frank yeah I don't think it has an exact equivalent, I'm paging through the doc trying to find it. Doh! you said `stri_detect`! That's it

Comment: @Frank please post `Dt[, stri_detect_fixed(title1, title2)]` as your own answer then, I don't want to steal from you

Comment: That's alright. I mentioned it here so that you could use it. (Also, the question is closed.) I suspect one of the main benefits of stringi here is vectorization.