# Regex on large text data (memory issues)

Tags: r, regex, loops, memory-management

I have a significantly large data frame `df`; it has 1,870,355 rows and 10 columns and one of them is `job.titles`. I also have a character vector containing job titles with 60,315 elements (`jobs`). I would like to match rows in the data frame which have job titles that also are in the character vector `jobs`.

For each element of `jobs`, I would like to know the rows of `df` with corresponding job titles.

The method I attempted is a combination of `lapply` and `grep`:

```
lapply(jobs, function(x) grep(pattern = x, x = df$job.titles, ignore.case = T)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.1 Mb
```

I think that the "vector" being referred to here is the `list` that was being created, which would have had a length of 60,315 elements. Moreover, each of these elements would have had various lengths and some could potentially have hundreds of thousands of elements.

I am well aware that examples must be reproducible to make it easy for readers to provide their help; however, there is no way I can make this reproducible. The code used actually works, but is limited by memory issues.

What can I do in cases like this?

Comment: Have you already cleared unnecessary items from your environment? 7.1 Mb is really small compared to the memory on modern computers.

Comment: I wonder if you will have the same issue if you use a PCRE regex. Try adding `perl=TRUE` to your `grep`. If you are checking against literal values, add `fixed=TRUE`. Also see [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365768/using-grep-to-subset-rows-from-a-data-table-comparing-row-content).

Comment: @Ryan I was actually surprised that I got this error because I have 16Gb of memory.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, it actually worked! The resulting list is a 17Mb list and the world is now a beautiful place. Would you please write an elaborate answer as to what the use of the argument `perl = TRUE` is and I will mark it as the correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: But have you tried without adding `perl=TRUE` and just adding `fixed=TRUE`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is what I am currently trying. Will report back when it's done. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think there is no point answering the same question twice. If it works, then you are using literal values to grep data, and there is already an answer on SO.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, `fixed = TRUE` actually works.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @MarioGS As I mentioned in the original question, reproducibility in this case is hard due to the dimensions/size of the data.